# How to install elinks on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-vista, makefile, elinks

I am using `bash-3.2` shell through cygwin to try to install [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/download.html) browser on my system. I am following [this](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/installation.html) documentation to install.

I am executing the following command:

```
./configure && make && make install
```

The setup fails saying:

```
error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates a problem with your compiler install, probably glibc headers or GCC. Try reinstalling GCC and the cpp modules, as well as glibc, glibc-headers and glibc-devel.

Comment: What is the best way to install all of these?

Comment: Well since these tools are required to install new packages, it will be faster to reinstall cygwin and select them from the list. They may not be named exactly as above, some may already be included in cygwin's glibc package.

Comment: okay. thanks. ill give it a try and let everyone know.

Answer (score 5):

Cygwin as an environment in not obligatory. Here is a Windows ready ELinks package without a need for Cygwin environment:

http://www.compmiscellanea.com/soft/windows/browsers/elinks/1/elinks-0.11.6.zip

- Download, unpack and run.

[ http://www.compmiscellanea.com/ru/konsolnye-prilozhenija-dlja-windows-veb-brauzery.htm#elinks ]

Answer (score 1):

Dirk Paehl compiles Windows binaries. You can download from here:

http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?TextBrowser_for_Windows:ELINKS_an_other_textbrowser